# CSS, menu on one line, middle element has 2 inner elements that need to stack without effecting menu items

Tags: html, css

The two elements in the div with the class "inline" need to be stacked, so the element containing "SECURITIES" needs to be under "A.M.S". The only problem is if I put 
 under the A.M.S element then the 3 menu items to the right also get put on a new line.

All of the menu items need to be on the same line. Here is my inspiration which you can see my desired effect. 
http://www.infinum.co/

**Edit 1**
Here is what it looks like at the moment:
http://cdpn.io/wlEpA

**Edit 2**
See image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63494571/howthis.jpg

I'm now having issues with giving my menu items the height of 100%. I want to be able to change the height of the "menu" div which will then affect the menu items so they stay in the center vertically.

At the moment though, the text isn't at the center of the element, and the top of the element is aligning to the top of the "SECURITIES" text instead of the top of the page. It should be as shown in the picture labeled "A".

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>AMS Securities</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color:#222222;
    margin:0px;
    font-family:Calibri;
}
.container {
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.content {
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    text-align:center;  
}
.inline { display:inline; }

.menu { text-align:center; height:84px; }
.menu_item { color:#bababa; font-size:18px; padding:1.5em; cursor:pointer; }
.menu_item:hover { color:#eb1217; }
.selected { color:#eb1217; border-top:#eb1217 4px solid; }

.title { color:#eb1217; font-size:52px; }
.sub_title { font-weight:bold; color:#f4f4f4; font-size:20px; }

.content {
    padding:3em 0em;    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="menu">
            <span class="menu_item selected">HOME</span>
            <span class="menu_item">VENUES</span>
            <span class="menu_item">PHOTOS</span>

            <div class="inline">
                <span class="title">A.M.S</span>
                <span class="sub_title">SECURITIES</span>
            </div>

            <span class="menu_item">ABOUT</span>
            <span class="menu_item">CONTACT</span>
            <span class="menu_item">LOGIN</span>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            content will go here
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Go to codepen.io and create a working model of your code, then link to it in your post. You'll get answers much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.inline` class should actually be set to `display: inline-block`, and you need to add `display: block` to your `.sub_title`. Make those changes and the issue you're referring to will be resolved. But then you'll notice that the entire menu is pushed down from the top. I started to solve this for you as well, but this is really basic css stuff, amigo. You'll need to restructure to make this work properly.

I'll give the following hints to set you on the right path:

- The menu is dropped because the whole thing is `display: inline` (which shouldn't be the case in the first place), so everything drops to the bottom of the containing element. The height of your logo and subtitle are what's breaking the layout, but again, making them shorter isn't the answer.
- You're going to want to replace those `span.menu_item`s with anchors.
- Check out professionally developed sites and inspect their menus using your browser's dev tools to get a feel for navigation best practices. Off the top of my head, zurb.com and css-tricks.com are good examples. And there's no shame in checking out the CSS powering the site you're knocking off. If you do so, you'll notice their menu items are all floated left.
- If you haven't already, check out a few CSS frameworks. Zurb's Foundation and Twitter's (formerly) Bootstrap are the most popular. They'll allow you to continue learning design and coding without having to nail everything at once, and they provide an excellent context for adopting best practices.

[Here's an updated CodePen.](http://codepen.io/erquhart/pen/xsqwE) Hope this helps.